# Does Availability Group between 2 failover cluster instances require a 4 node WSFC cluster?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

I have 2 SQL Server Failover Clustering Instances (FCI). Each FCI consists of a 2-node Windows Server Failover Cluster.

I want to setup an Availability Group between the 2 FCIs.

One of the prerequisites for Availability Groups is that participant nodes must belong to the same Windows Server Failover Cluster.

Does this mean I will need to move the nodes from 1 WSFC into the other WSFC, so I effectively have a 4-node Windows Server Failover Cluster wherein FCI1=Node1/Node2; and FCI2=Node3/Node4?

Is that correct way to do this?

Comment: What are your use requirements? We can guess at how you plan on using this configuration, but writing a totally generic pro/con list is difficult. Narrowing the scope by including your requirements, rather than just 2 proposed solutions will improve your chances of getting an answer. Will you need to fail over between FCIs? Are the two clusters in the same subnet? In the same data center? Do you perceive that one option is preferred? Why?

Comment: I have added more context to my question

Comment: I have to agree with the others who have voted to close this question as opinion based. There is still not enough detail here for me to say "This is what you should do.". Details that would be good are things such as, "what are the business needs for HA/DR", "what is the RTO", "will each FCI be in the same data center". These are all crucial details.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey- I have read the AG (HA) requires all nodes to be in a single WSFC. So does that mean option 2 is impossible and option 1 is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The typical setup for 4 nodes the way you are describing it would be to have two separate Availability Groups.  Each individual Availability Group confers High Availability.  Something like this:

1. AG1

   - Server 1
   - Server 2
2. AG2

   - Server 3
   - Server 4

At this point you have two independent Availability Groups.  You then create a Distributed Availability Group spanning AG1 and AG2.  The Distributed Availability Group offers Disaster Recovery typically by having AG2 in a different data center.  We'll refer to that as DistributedAG.  Data is synchronized between Server 1 and Server 2 via standard Availability Groups mirroring process.  Data between the primary node of AG1 is synchronized to AG2 via a similar independent mirroring process.  Synchronization between AG1 and AG2 can be either synchronous or asynchronous, and failover is always a manual act in the current version of SQL Server.

Client access to the Distributed Availability Group can be configured via a DNS CNAME record for DistributedAG that points at either AG1 or AG2 depending on which of the two target Availability Groups is hosting the primary AG.

AG1 and AG2 both have their own listeners, and both are capable of providing read-only routing and serving data.  Only one of the nodes can ever be the writable primary instance.

Configuring a Distributed Availability Group is a complex process, and is fairly well described in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=automatic)

Answer (score 0):

One such configuration I've seen (not to debate if proper or not), is a stretch cluster across two data centers. FCI 1 in DC 1, FCI 2 in DC 2. All nodes are part of the same cluster with preferred owners set accordingly to limit each FCI's failover targets to the local DC. Then AG used for replication between the two data centers.

I'm not a big fan of this configuration, and typically only see if for VLBs to the tune of 20-30TB, where the business doesn't want to pay for duplicate storage for all four nodes.

The other more common trend prior to AG was for companies to build 3 node clusters and put two FCIs on them, allowing one node for overlap. Basically providing a single node as a failover target for two different FCI's. Again, not an ideal configuration, but one that was often used back in the 2008 days. This is far less common these days.